# The meaning of に in [切り出すに切り出せず]

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-に

I don't understand the meaning of に in this sentence:

> 切り出すに切り出せず、今日まできてしまいました

Is 切り出すに切り出せず fashioned after some particular grammar? I can't really think of an interpretation that sounds natural.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「Verb + に（or にも） + ***Same*** Verb in ***potential*** form + ず」

is a very common phrase pattern that expresses one's inability or hesitation to perform the action described by the verb.

See 一-2 in:  https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82-592921#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89

> 「[切]{き}り[出]{だ}すに切り出せず、[今日]{きょう}まできてしまいました。」

means:

> "I have not been quite able to bring up (this) topic until today."

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a grammatical construction where you have a verb in base form plus に followed by a negative potential form of the same verb. It basically means that for some prohibiting reason, you couldn't do ~~~ even if you wanted to.

終電を逃したから、帰るには帰れない。(Paraphrasing, "I missed the last train and I have no way to get home.")

It looks like in the sentence you shared, it would mean something like, "(No matter how much I wanted to) I had no way to bring it up..."

Comment: ×「帰るには帰れない」--> ○「帰るに帰れない」「帰るにも帰れない」「帰ろうにも帰れない」 or 「帰りたくても帰れない」

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, it means 切り出したかったのに切り出せず. (切り出す = to broach (a topic))

`[dictionary form of a verb] + に + [nai-form] + ない` is an uncommon, emphatic, and literary set phrase which means "want to ～ but can't", "too bad/extraordinary to ～", etc.

> - 泣くに泣けない状況 a situation too bad to cry
> - 笑うに笑えない話 a story too extraordinary to laugh at
> - この料理は食うに食えない this dish is too bad to eat (tastes awful)
> - 食うに食えない生活を送る have difficulty to live on (because of poverty)

I think this に corresponds to either of the two definitions of [this page](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/166083/m0u/%E3%81%AB/):

> ［格助］名詞、名詞に準じる語、動詞の連用形・連体形などに付く。
>   13 （動詞・形容詞を重ねて）強意を表す。「騒ぎ―騒ぐ」
>   「風いたう吹き、海の面(おもて)ただあし―あしうなるに」〈枕・三〇六〉
>
> ［接助］活用語の連体形に付く。
>   3 逆接の確定条件を表す。…けれども。…のに。…だが。
>   「日中の照りに乾いて、きょうは道が好かった―、小庭の苔はまだ濡れている」〈鴎外・蛇〉