# Dictionary form of verb as nouns

Tags: verbs, dictionary

About verb modify as nouns
Normally verb if want to treat as nouns is add こと/物 /の
Today learned verb dictionary+に限る
Why it is use dictionary form verb instead of stem form 
From what I learn before verb stem + に行く,verb stem is used 
Does it mean に限る , the verb before に is treat as nouns? 
Example 疲れた時はお風呂に入るに限る
Is 入る as a nouns?How can に be put after a verb's plain form? What is this usage? Learned に can be put after a verb stem so far only 
Can verb directly use as a nouns?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, に can come directly after the dictionary form of a verb in **many** situations. It's hard to generalize.

- [Dictionary form of verb followed by に](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27907/5010) (学校へ行くには早い)
- [には with plain form of verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29886/5010) (いるにはいる, 書くには書く)
- [What does the に do in 表情から察するに?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29418/5010)
- [volitional + nimo 作ろう＋にも?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38540/5010)
- [The meaning of に in [切り出すに切り出せず]](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24130/5010)

It may be best to memorize each pattern without thinking too much. But in case you're curious, に was an [archaic conjunctive particle](https://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa010017.htm) similar to modern と/ので/のに, and it is still surviving in some constructions of modern Japanese. In addition, there was no nominalizer の/こと in archaic Japanese. In modern Japanese, sometimes the dictionary-form (or, to be exact, attributive-form) of a verb can act as a noun in certain proverbs and idioms. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64661/5010).