Why is the particle に marking a verb?
I came across the description for a Japanese word that left me puzzled. It is the third one for 目標 which is the following: 行動を進めるにあたって、実現・達成をめざす水準。 I have learned, that the に particle can only mark nouns. So what does the に do here? Furthermore, how would the sentence be translated? Applying the continuing action, the desired level is reached?

"It is the third one for 目標 " - what does this mean? If you are referring to a specific published source, you should show us what it is. Anyone can write definitions for 目標 in a variety of different ways and put them in any order.

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27907/902

I got the Definition from here:https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%9B%AE%E6%A8%99/#jn-218976

I have found my answer in this post: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/66427/dictionary-form-of-verb-as-nouns/66431#66431
